# bundle install fails installing ruby-oci8 on osx 10.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I ran 'bundle install' with ruby 2.0 and when it gets to the ruby-oci8 gem it fails.

```
"xcrun clang -o conftest -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/universal-darwin13 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -I/opt/oracle_11_2/instantclient_11_2/rdbms/public conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib -L. -L/usr/local/lib   -arch x86_64 -arch i386   -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib  -L/opt/oracle_11_2/instantclient_11_2/lib -lclntsh -lruby.2.0.0  -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib  -L/opt/oracle_11_2/instantclient_11_2/lib -lclntsh -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:7:29: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 5, have 0
int t(void) { OCIInitialize(); return 0; }
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/opt/oracle_11_2/instantclient_11_2/rdbms/public/ociap.h:7085:1: note: 'OCIInitialize' declared here
sword   OCIInitialize   (ub4 mode, void  *ctxp,
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out I had the 32 bit instead of the 64 bit oracle instantclient